# Reading a file characterwise in java

Tags: java, filereader

Like C language use fgetc() function to read a file characterwise how this can be done in java?? Scanner class reads a file line by line or word by word.. Also someone used a method   to take up a word in a String and then use tocharArray to convert into character array.I dont want this solutions.. Do any one have any easy solution like fgetc() does in C??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that what C calls a `char`, Java calls a `byte`.

You want to open an `InputStream` on your file (using `Files.newInputStream()`). Then, you will `.read()` from the `InputStream`. That is the closest thing to C's `fgetc()`.

That is for *binary* data. If you want to read text instead you'll have to use a `Reader`.

You may want to have a look [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for the full story, because it isn't obvious at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `read()` method on the `InputStream`, as long as you don't have multiple objects reading from it (such as a `Scanner` on the same stream). If you want C-equivalent, `nextByte()` on the `Scanner` might be what you're looking for.